# Error:You're not allowed to extend classes that define Step Definitions or hooks

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, annotations, cucumber

I have next error:

> You're not allowed to extend classes that define Step Definitions or
> hooks.

Please see the error below.

How can I fix my problem? I want create many classes, with steps for Cucumber, and a class Hook with preconditions in `@Before` and `@After`

My class Hook

```
public class Hook {
    public WebDriver driver;

    protected Properties properties;
    protected final String propertyFilePath = "src/main/java/Config/config.properties";

    /**
     * read data from config file
     **/
    public Hook() {
        BufferedReader reader;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(propertyFilePath));
            properties = new Properties();
            try {
                properties.load(reader);
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("config.properties not found at " + propertyFilePath);
        }
    }

    @Before
    /**pattern singleton*/
    public String getDriverPath() {
        String browser = properties.getProperty("browser");
        if (browser.equals("chrome")) {
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        } else if (browser.equals("firefox")) {
            WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        } else {
            System.out.println("browser not existed");
        }
        driver.manage().window().fullscreen();
        String url = properties.getProperty("url");
        driver.get(url);
        return browser;
    }

    @After
    public void close() {
        driver.quit();
    }
```

My class BaseSteps:

```
public class BaseSteps extends Hook {

    @When("fill in Name with {string}")
    public void fillInWith(String value) {
        LoginPage loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
        loginPage.typeInUserNameField(value);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, Cucumber doesn't allow extending classes that have step definitions or hooks. But you can use composition to get where you need to go.

1. Modify the Hook class to remove the @Before and @After annotations and create separate methods for the setup and teardown:

```java
public class Hook {
    // ... (all other existing code in your Hook class)

    public void setup() {
        String browser = getDriverPath();
        // ... (all other code in the previous @Before annotated method)
    }

    public void tearDown() {
        close();
    }
}
```

2. Create a new class TestContext to manage the shared state (in this case, the Hook instance):

```java
public class TestContext {
    private Hook hook;

    public TestContext() {
        hook = new Hook();
    }

    public Hook getHook() {
        return hook;
    }
}
```

3. Modify your BaseSteps class to use composition instead of inheritance:

```java
public class BaseSteps {
    private TestContext testContext;

    public BaseSteps(TestContext testContext) {
        this.testContext = testContext;
    }

    @When("fill in Name with {string}")
    public void fillInWith(String value) {
        LoginPage loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(testContext.getHook().driver, LoginPage.class);
        loginPage.typeInUserNameField(value);
    }
}
```

Finally, create a new class CucumberHooks to hold your @Before and @After hooks:

```java
public class CucumberHooks {
    private TestContext testContext;

    public CucumberHooks(TestContext testContext) {
        this.testContext = testContext;
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        testContext.getHook().setup();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        testContext.getHook().tearDown();
    }
}
```

Now your step classes (e.g., BaseSteps) will not directly extend the Hook class, and the shared state will be managed using the TestContext class. This should resolve the error you're encountering.

Comment: Oh thank you very much,but now I have next error(java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "this.searchContext" is null and browser was not opened

Comment: I could be wrong, but that sounds like a separate issue, which needs more context for someone to be able to solve. If this answer got you passed the first error, would you mark it as correct and create a new question?